# How to change an attribute value of an Object inside an Interceptor?

Tags: hibernate, cdi, interceptor

How to change an attribute value of a Product, just before post?

Which attribute or value should I modify on this Interceptor context?

This is not working:

```
@Interceptor
@BeforePost
public class BeforePostInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

        for (Object o : context.getParameters()) {
            if (o instanceof Product) {
                Product product = (Product)o;
                product.setSku(product.getSku().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, this question has nothing to do with `hibernate`.  Perhaps you might want to add more appropriate tags so that your question is visible to the right communities.

Comment: Sure you need cdi interceptors? Are you not just looking for entitylisteners?